# Rails + Rspec. Michael Hartl tutorial. Implementing sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm getting this error that could not find the function but I can't understand why. Here is my code:

> session_helper.rb

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    current_user = user
  end
...
...
```

> session_controller.rb

```
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      @title = "Sign in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in(user)
      redirect_to user
    end
  end
```

> sessions_controller_spec.rb

```
    it "should sign the user in" do 
      post :create, session: @attr
      expect(controller.current_user).to eq @user
      expect(controller).to be_signed_in
    end

    it "should redirect to the user show page" do 
      post :create, session: @attr
      expect(response).to redirect_to(user_path(@user))
    end
```

> Rspec

```
  2) SessionsController success should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: post :create, session: @attr
     NoMethodError:
     undefined method `sign_in' for #<SessionsController:0x00000006409380>
```

If I put the function sign_in in the sessions_controller I don't get this error but if I keep the function in the helper my program just doesn't see the function. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include SessionsHelper` in `ApplicationController` or `SessionsController`.
Helper methods are not directly accessible in controllers. You need to include them.

Comment: Glad to help.:) Please accept the answer when timeout is over.

Answer (score -1):

You should include helper module. Add this to spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include SessionHelper #add this line
  ...
end
```

Comment: The error is happening in the controller. Including it in the test is not going to fix it.